# How to place a conditional check inside springboot project reactor Mono stream (written in Kotlin)?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

Pretty new to project reactor here, I am struggling to put a conditional check inside my Mono stream. This part of my application is receiving an object from Kafka. Let's say the object is like this.

```
data class SomeEvent(val id: String, val type: String)
```

I have a function that handles this object like this.

```
fun process(someEvent: SomeEvent): Mono<String> {
  val id = someEvent.id
  val checkCondition = someEvent.type == "thisType"

  return repoOne.getItem(id)
    .map {item ->
      // WHAT DO I DO HERE TO PUT A CONDITIONAL CHECK
      createEntryForItem(item)
    }
    .flatMap {entry ->
      apiService.sendEntry(entry)
    }
    .flatMap {
      it.bodyToMono(String::class.java)
    }
    .flatMap {body ->
      Mono.just(body)
    }
}
```

So, what I want to do is check whether `checkCondition` is `true` and if it is, I want to call a function `repoTwo.getDetails(id)` that returns a `Mono<Details>`.

`createEntryForItem` returns an object of type `Entry`

`apiService.sendEntry(entry)` returns a `Mono<ClientResponse>`

It'd be something like this (in my mind).

```
fun process(someEvent: SomeEvent): Mono<String> {
  val id = someEvent.id
  val checkCondition = someEvent.type == "thisType"

  return repoOne.getItem(id)
    .map {item ->
      if (checkCondition) {
        repoTwo.getDetails(id).map {details ->
          createEntryForItem(item, details)
        }
      } else {
        createEntryForItem(item)
      }          
    }
    .flatMap {entry ->
      apiService.sendEntry(entry)
    }
    .flatMap {
      it.bodyToMono(String::class.java)
    }
    .flatMap {body ->
      Mono.just(body)
    }
}
```

But, obviously, this does not work because the expression inside the `if statement` is cast to `Any`.

How should I write it to achieve what I want to achieve?

UPDATED: The location of where I like to have the conditional check.

Comment: My answer didn't worked for you? Can you check it, please? :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `flatMap()` and not `map()` after `getItem()`.

```
return repoOne.getItem(id)
    .flatMap {item ->
      if (checkCondition) {
        repoTwo.getDetails(id).map {details ->
          createEntryForItem(item, details)
        }
      } else {
        Mono.just(createEntryForItem(item))
      }          
    }
```

In a `map{}` you can transform the value. Because you want to call `getDetails()` (which returns a reactive type and not a value) to do that you have to use `flatMap{}`. And that's why you need to wrap your item in a `Mono` by calling `Mono.just(createEntryForItem(item))` on the else branch.

Comment: apologies I just realised I put the conditional piece at the wrong spot. I already updated the question.

Comment: That conditional clause doesn't give me the warning of automatic casting to `Unit`, however, the following `flatMap` does not work anymore because `apiService.sendEntry(entry)` expects `entry: Entry`. Currently, it is `Mono<Entry>`. How do I get around this?

Also, are you able to give an explanation on why doing `Mono.just(createEntryForItem(item))` makes the conditional clause work?

Comment: From the `flatMap` you have to return a `Mono`. You cannot just return a value. Check the documentation of [flatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) and [map](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: `map` works for you if you want to transform the item into another type and you can do it without calling another reactive function. example:
`getUser().map { user -> user.name } ` But with flatMap you can include other reactive calls in you chain: `getUser().flatMap { user -> downloadImage(user.imageUrl) }` But you can't mix up the two types in one call.

Answer (score 0):

Just split it to another function. Your code will be cleaner too.

```
repoOne.getItem(id)
    .map { createEntry(it, checkCondition) }.
    .flatMap.....


private fun createEntry(item, checkCondition): Item {
  return if (checkCondition) {
      repoTwo.getDetails(id).map { createEntryForItem(item, it) }        
  } else {
      createEntryForItem(item)
  }
}
```

Comment: What about the details? I need to get it from repoTwo.getDetails(id)

Comment: I updated it as your updated example. It's hard to be more specific without knowing the types.

Comment: sorry, which object type would help you to improve your answer?

Comment: None that would really add to my answer, but just to make the return type of the private function explicit (the return type of createEntryForItem)